# Plot Interactive graph for live data

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly, jupyter

I created a function which fetch data from machine and its a huge data.

```py
    def fun():
        import pandas as pd
        import time
        import sys
        sys.path.append('/apps/data/myfile')
        import report
        reload(report)
        from IPython.display import display,clear_output
        while True:
             clear_output()
             df = report.mydf(g = "")
             display(df)
             time.sleep(30)
```

This function will display updated df in every 30 sec like below image.
[image: DataFrame]
I want to plot **P/L vs NowTime** for each Symbol in jupyter for this continuance df.
please guide me.

Comment: Noted @DavidW thanks for your comment.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) and search here on SO (for ex https://stackoverflow.com/a/65508519/1356000). Update your question when you have tried to implement something and have a *specific* problem and a *specific* question